# query on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
SELECT
    A.IdDepartment,
    A.IdParent,
    A.Localidad,
    A.Codigo,
    A.Nombre,
    A.Departamento,
    A.Fecha,
    A.[Registro Entrada],
    A.[Registro Salida],
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT IdUser FROM Exception WHERE IdUser =  A.Codigo) <> ''
            THEN(SELECT Description FROM Exception WHERE IdUser = A.Codigo AND A.Fecha BETWEEN BeginingDate AND EndingDate)
        ELSE ('Ausente')
    END AS Novedades
FROM VW_HORARIOS A
WHERE  A.[Registro Entrada] = A.[Registro Salida]
GROUP BY A.IdDepartment,A.IdParent, A.Localidad, A.Codigo, A.Nombre, A.Departamento, A.Fecha, A.[Registro Entrada],A.[Registro Salida]
ORDER BY A.Fecha
```

the query performs the following selects all the records placed in the following query, what I want to validate is the following if on a date there was no record I want to create it but I do not know how to create that record because it does not exist, if someone can help me I would appreciate the help

[image: data]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you are trying to do.  Also, if you are focused on a dates, then perhaps the query can be simplified.

Comment: Sounds like a calendar table is going to be useful here.

Comment: Images of data aren't helpful to others. Please post in in a consumable format with DDL: [How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/).

Comment: Use af date dimension to join between dates and then you will have your "extra rows"

Comment: @GordonLinoff 
place the image in the description for you to see, if you look at the image has a date field if you look at the date 2018-01-09 and 10 are not what I want is if you are not creating a record with that data

Comment: @plaidDK 
I have no idea how to do it

Comment: which values do you want on the new created rows? The date, but what about the resT?

Comment: @plaidDK The location, code, name, department, date others I want to be null or empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. Just fill out your own Date table with values that is within your range of dates.

> Remember to verify the last join. I dont know if that is the unique businesskey within your data sample

**SQL Test Code**

```
declare @DateTable table (Dates date)
insert into @DateTable

values
('2017-01-01'),
('2017-01-02'),
('2017-01-03'),
('2017-01-04'),
('2017-01-05'),
('2017-01-06'),
('2017-01-07'),
('2017-01-08'),
('2017-01-09'),
('2017-01-10')

declare @SamleTable table (DateStamp date,Department nvarchar(50),LocationId nvarchar(50),Code int,name nvarchar(50),Entrada nvarchar(50))
insert into @SamleTable
values
('2017-01-01','BOTELLO','SANTO',5540,'JOSE','Something'),
('2017-01-04','BOTELLO','SANTO',5540,'JOSE','Something'),
('2017-01-06','BOTELLO','SANTO',5540,'JOSE','Something'),
('2017-01-09','BOTELLO','SANTO',5540,'JOSE','Something')

select z.Department,z.LocationId,z.Code,z.name,z.Dates,COALESCE(a.Entrada,'EMPTY') as Entrada from (
Select Department,LocationId,Code,Name,Dates from (
select Department,LocationId,Code,Name,MIN(DateStamp) mind, MAX(Datestamp) maxd from @SamleTable
group by Department,LocationId,Code,Name
 )x
 CROSS JOIN @DateTable b 
 where b.Dates between x.mind and x.maxd
 ) z
 left join @SamleTable a on a.Department = z.Department and a.LocationId = z.LocationId and a.Code = z.Code and a.name = z.name
 and a.DateStamp = z.Dates
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I have two view one that shows me the data and another that presents all the dates one of the views is called vw_horarios and the other vw_shift_date that has all the dates as I have several records I would like to know how valid that user is not registered that day

Comment: What? How should i know why your user is not registered?

Comment: that's what I want if on that date the user does not have a record I want it to be created with the user's data and the date

Comment: Thats just what i did?

Comment: but you could modify the query to read me from the view called vw_shift_date that has a date field to understand better

Comment: I dont know how your views look like. Just replace the variable tables with your views, and correct the names to fit your views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query building all dates from the minimum date to the maximum date found in your table.

```
with dates(fecha, maxfecha) as
(
  select min(fecha) as fecha, max(fecha) as maxfecha from vw_horarios
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, 1, fecha) as fecha, maxfecha from dates where fecha < maxfecha
)
select d.fecha, q.*
from dates d
left join ( your query here ) q on q.fecha = d.fecha;
```

Comment: if I still have another table not vw_shift_date that contains all the dates you can not use that view to verify a record is not based on that date that has

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Anyway, if you want to take the dates from your query only, then use: `with myquery as (your query here), dates(fecha, maxfecha) as (select min(fecha) as fecha, max(fecha) as maxfecha from myquery union all ...) select d.fecha, q.* from dates d
left join myquery q on q.fecha = d.fecha;` instead.